Dio Issues when get response from server
I found error like that window.onload=function(){window.location.href="/lander?codes=privacy-policy%2Cuser-agreement%2Crecharge-page%2Ctrading-rule%2Ccustomer-service"} when I get response,
So how to resolve it?
I using dio: ^5.4.1

please provide more detail or an error log so that we can understand better

example like this.    Future<BaseResponse<List>> getStocks({required Map<String, dynamic> request}) async {
var response = await DioClient.getMethod(
path: '/api/v1/stocks',
queryParameters: request,
parseData: (data) => (data as List).map((_item) => StockItemModel.fromJson(_item)).toList(),
);
return response;
}
